# Python Lists: Why is the Pythonic list comprehension 8-20% slower?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization

**(Update: The issue has been found. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77922551/8874388). This turned out to be a performance issue in Python 3.11, and only affects small lists. For Python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.12, list comprehension is ALWAYS faster, regardless of list size.)**

I've seen claims that "list comprehension is always faster because it avoids the lookup and calling of the `append()` method".

The difference is how appending is done:

- List comprehensions use just two bytecodes, `LOAD_FAST(k); LIST_APPEND`.
- Regular `.append()` calls use five bytecodes, one of which is a method lookup (hash table), `LOAD_METHOD(append); LOAD_FAST(k); PRECALL; CALL; POP_TOP`.

So obviously, list comprehension *should* be faster since it avoids costly function lookups/calls...

But no matter how I twist this, I see two things:

- List comprehension is 8-20% slower than `.append()`. A friend verified this on their computer too.
- The disassembly for list comprehension is way longer, which may explain why it's slower.

Does anyone know what's going on? Why is the Pythonic "list comprehension" so much slower?

I am running Python 3.11 on Linux. He is running Windows. So it's slower on both platforms.

My code is below.

```py
from typing import Any


def filter_unset_loop(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = []
    for k, v in new_settings.items():
        if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config"):
            remove_keys.append(k)

    for k in remove_keys:
        del new_settings[k]

    return new_settings


def filter_unset_listcomp(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = [
        k for k, v in new_settings.items() if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config")
    ]

    for k in remove_keys:
        del new_settings[k]

    return new_settings


def test_loop():
    filter_unset_loop(
        {},
        {
            "self": True,
            "what": None,
            "hello": "world",
            "great": "key",
            "1": 1,
            "2": 1,
            "3": 1,
            "4": 1,
            "5": 1,
            "6": 1,
            "7": 1,
            "8": 1,
            "9": 1,
            "10": 1,
            "11": 1,
            "12": 1,
            "13": 1,
            "14": 1,
            "15": 1,
            "16": 1,
        },
    )



def test_listcomp():
    filter_unset_listcomp(
        {},
        {
            "self": True,
            "what": None,
            "hello": "world",
            "great": "key",
            "1": 1,
            "2": 1,
            "3": 1,
            "4": 1,
            "5": 1,
            "6": 1,
            "7": 1,
            "8": 1,
            "9": 1,
            "10": 1,
            "11": 1,
            "12": 1,
            "13": 1,
            "14": 1,
            "15": 1,
            "16": 1,
        },
    )


import timeit
n = 20_000_000
t1 = timeit.Timer(test_loop)
print("loop (seconds):", t1.timeit(number=n))
t2 = timeit.Timer(test_listcomp)
print("listcomp (seconds):", t2.timeit(number=n))

import dis

print("\nLOOP DISASSEMBLY:\n")

dis.dis(filter_unset_loop)

print("\n" * 10)
print("\nLISTCOMP DISASSEMBLY:\n")

dis.dis(filter_unset_listcomp)
```

Comment: list comprehensions are just for-loops that use append. You have other things going on here, you aren't comparing the loops directly. I suspect if you isolate the for-loop with append and the list comprehension, the differences will be marginal, although, typically they are slightly in favor of the list comprehension

Comment: also, your test data is miniscule, so these differences are probably pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "list comprehensions are just for-loops that use append" That's not true. List comprehensions use `LOAD_FAST(k); LIST_APPEND` bytecodes. For-loops with append use `LOAD_METHOD(append); LOAD_FAST(k); PRECALL; CALL; POP_TOP`. This is why people say that List Comprehension is much faster. Because it does less work to append each item... As for the "extra things going on", it's just a "del" call with 2-item lists in both situations, so that's not the explanation. If we look at the disassembly, the only thing that stands out is that list comprehension is WAY more bytecode.

Comment: No one says that list comprehensions are much faster if they know what they are talking about. Yes, you avoid the method resolution overhead, but list comprehensions, in the best case, are only *marginally faster*. As the work done inside the mapping/filtering clauses increases, they come to dominate the runtime, and then the performance is pretty much the same. List comprehensions **are not for performance*. They are for *expressiveness*. they are nice, declarative ways of expressing mapping/filtering operations. They have a few small optimizations, but that isn't their purpose

Comment: And by the way, **what you described is a for-loop that uses append**, albeit, with it's own specialized opcode. But it is calling `list.append` all the same. The work required to do the actual `.append` is exactly the same, it just gets to `.append` slightly more optimized

Comment: In any case, if I just time the list comprehension, I get 21.34864 seconds for the loop, 21.01230 seconds for the list comprehension, so negligible difference that slightly favors the list comprehension (exactly as you would expect)

Comment: I think you should narrow your question to "in this case." Comprehension is not universally slower as your title and question implies. e.g. `timeit.timeit("l = [x for x in range(1000)]", number=100000)` vs. `timeit.timeit("l=[]\nfor x in range(1000): l.append(x)", number=100000)`. Comprehension is *much* faster in this simple example.

Comment: @Woodford eh, put those both in a function and the differences will narrow significantly (because the list comprehension is implicitly done in a function scope, making all the variable lookups fast, whereas your loop does a hash-based lookup for every variable lookup -- note, in Python 3.12, list comps no longer create a function). If you *really* want to almost remove the difference, do something like `l=[];append = l.append\nfor x in range(1000): append(x)"`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's fine but doesn't negate my point that the question asserts that comprehensions are outright slower instead of trying to understand why they are slower in this particular application.

Comment: In OP's example here, only 10% of iterations actually result in an `append`, so the overall cost of looking up the method is going to be less significant than in scenarios where you'd append on every iteration.

Comment: Note, if I run your code exactly (without isolating the list comprehension), I get the loop: `37.446` and the listcomp: `37.691`. So something in the "something else" which accounting for these differences (note, you are also re-creating the data, since you have to, since you modify the inputs)

Comment: @slothrop yes, but regardless, what you see if you actually just compare the list comprehension to the loop (without removing from the dict, and without re-creating the dict) you get a marginally faster list comprehension, **exactly** as you would expect, and I'm willing to bet you get that same result on windows or linux (I happen to be on Mac at the moment)

Comment: @slothrop **I have posted a new example as a separate answer,** where I use 10 000 list items, thereby triggering 10 000 `.append()` calls per test. This made list comprehensions slightly faster, since they avoid the `.append()` method lookup and call overhead. So yeah, it really depends. For small amounts of work, loops are faster, presumably because of the larger bytecode involved in setting up a list comprehension. But for large amounts of work, list comprehension is faster. But in either case, the differences don't matter much! I suppose list comprehension for code neatness is the winner.

Comment: Python 3.12.0 on linux:
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer(test_loop)
loop (seconds): 26.104925561001437
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer(test_listcomp)
listcomp (seconds): 26.089847875999112
Timing basically the same

Comment: @JacekBłocki in 3.12, list have lower overhead! They no longer create functions internally

Comment: python 3.10.8 your code shows performance is essentially the same for me with one being slightly faster on some runs the other on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR answer:

- In Python 3.12, list comprehension is always faster for everything.
- In Python 3.11, list comprehension is always slower for small lists but always faster for large lists.
- In Python 3.10 and 3.9, list comprehension is always faster for everything.

So the issue only happens in Python 3.11. They most likely changed some code related to initialization of list comprehensions in that version, which gave it an unfair overhead penalty. They've fixed it in 3.12, and it wasn't an issue in 3.9 and 3.10.

Recommendation: Use list comprehensions. They are better. :)

---

### Longer answer and detailed tests:

Alright, the answer is that it depends.

It depends on how many `.append()` operations you will be doing, and it also depends on your Python version!

For Python 3.12, 3.10 and 3.9, List Comprehension is UNIVERSALLY FASTER (see bottom/final edit of this answer for more info about that).

For Python 3.11, List Comprehension is slower in some cases, as follows:

- For short loops with low amounts of `.append()`, list comprehension's overhead means that it's slower, as seen in my original question.
- But as the amount of loop iterations grows, and thereby the amount of `.append()` calls, the list comprehension begins to gain a performance lead.

Here's the updated test where I generate a dictionary with over 10 000 keys, which thereby made the `loop/.append()` variant about 6.5% slower than list comprehension due to having so many elements (tons of `append()` calls), basically inversing the performance, when testing this in Python 3.11.

List comprehension is preferable since it keeps the code cleaner and is always faster for lots of appends, and also makes your code more future-proof.

Here's my modified test with 10 000 items:

```py
from typing import Any


def filter_unset_loop(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = []
    for k, v in new_settings.items():
        if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config"):
            remove_keys.append(k)

    for k in remove_keys:
        del new_settings[k]

    return new_settings


def filter_unset_listcomp(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = [
        k for k, v in new_settings.items() if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config")
    ]

    for k in remove_keys:
        del new_settings[k]

    return new_settings


def make_dict(out: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    for k in range(10000):
        out[str(k)] = 1
    
    return out


test_dict_template = make_dict({
    "self": True,
    "what": None,
    "hello": "world",
    "great": "key",
})


def test_loop():
    filter_unset_loop(
        {},
        test_dict_template.copy(),
    )



def test_listcomp():
    filter_unset_listcomp(
        {},
        test_dict_template.copy(),
    )


import timeit
n = 100_000
t1 = timeit.Timer(test_loop)
print("loop (seconds):", t1.timeit(number=n))
t2 = timeit.Timer(test_listcomp)
print("listcomp (seconds):", t2.timeit(number=n))

import dis

print("\nLOOP DISASSEMBLY:\n")

dis.dis(filter_unset_loop)

print("\n" * 10)
print("\nLISTCOMP DISASSEMBLY:\n")

dis.dis(filter_unset_listcomp)
```

### Update:

Since Juan wanted me to do a test without any `del` statement, and with a global dictionary (so that it isn't recreated for every test), I have now done that.

When I do that, List Comprehension is 9% slower than for-append for me, in Python 3.11.

It really seems to come down to the way that list comprehensions generate a lot more bytecode to "prepare the list comprehension", which is its own form of overhead.

(Edit: This list comprehension performance issue only happens in Python 3.11, as further testing below revealed.)

```py
from typing import Any


def filter_unset_loop(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = []
    for k, v in new_settings.items():
        if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config"):
            remove_keys.append(k)

    return new_settings


def filter_unset_listcomp(
    settings: dict[str, Any],
    new_settings: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    remove_keys: list[str] = [
        k for k, v in new_settings.items() if (v is None or k == "self" or k == "config")
    ]

    return new_settings


settings: dict[str, Any] = {}
new_settings: dict[str, Any] = {
    "self": True,
    "what": None,
    "hello": "world",
    "great": "key",
    "1": 1,
    "2": 1,
    "3": 1,
    "4": 1,
    "5": 1,
    "6": 1,
    "7": 1,
    "8": 1,
    "9": 1,
    "10": 1,
    "11": 1,
    "12": 1,
    "13": 1,
    "14": 1,
    "15": 1,
    "16": 1,
}


def test_loop():
    filter_unset_loop(
        settings,
        new_settings,
    )



def test_listcomp():
    filter_unset_listcomp(
        settings,
        new_settings,
    )


import timeit
n = 30_000_000
t1 = timeit.Timer(test_loop)
print("loop (seconds):", t1.timeit(number=n))
t2 = timeit.Timer(test_listcomp)
print("listcomp (seconds):", t2.timeit(number=n))
```

### Final Update: Reason found! Python 3.12 has optimized List Comprehensions!

Since some commenters wanted to use timeit to check the differences, but they used incorrect timeit commands, here are the accurate comparisons which use local variables and appropriate amounts of iterations.

Most importantly, I found out what's going on! Python 3.12 has optimized List Comprehensions. In Python 3.11, list comprehensions are 22% slower than `.append()` for small lists. In Python 3.12 they are always universally faster.

```
$ pyenv local 3.11  

$ python --version    
Python 3.11.7

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 "x=[]" "for i in range(100_000): x.append(i)"
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.72 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 "x=[i for i in range(100_000)]"  
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.34 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 10000000 "x=[]" "for i in range(10): x.append(i)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 191 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 10000000 "x=[i for i in range(10)]"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 234 nsec per loop

$ pyenv local 3.12                                       

$ python --version
Python 3.12.1

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 "x=[]" "for i in range(100_000): x.append(i)"
1000 loops, best of 5: 2.36 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 "x=[i for i in range(100_000)]"
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.69 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 10000000 "x=[]" "for i in range(10): x.append(i)"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 204 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 10000000 "x=[i for i in range(10)]"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 160 nsec per loop
```

### Update with fixed version of @JonSG's code, to add another data point to this.

JonSG's answer had some good ideas, but his numbers were completely invalid, since he ran so few iterations of each test that the numbers were completely useless. (His code ran the tests for just a few nanoseconds per test...)

I rewrote the test to run an appropriate amount of tests per iteration, to account for variations in background tasks, random CPU cache stutters, CPU throttling, fluctuations in CPU boost frequency, etc.

After fixing his tests, his tests confirm what I discovered above:

- Python 3.12 is universally faster when using List Comprehensions.
- Python 3.11 is faster with `for-append()` loops for small lists, but loops are slower when the lists are longer. The reason for this slowness for small lists is probably due to the fact that list comprehension requires creating a new stack frame, which in turn requires a lot of bytecode. So there's lots of overhead for "starting" a list comprehension in Python 3.11. This process was clearly not optimized well in older versions of Python. (Edit: This performance issue only affects Python 3.11, see further tests of older Python versions below!)
- My recommendation/conclusion is still: Despite the bad results in Python 3.11, I will always use list comprehensions, because it's the most universally futureproof technique, and is always the best whenever the list is long. So it's not worth worrying about the small edge cases ("small lists, certain old Python versions"), in my opinion.

```py
import sys
import timeit

def test_loop(n):
    foo = []
    for i in range(n):
        foo.append(i)
    return foo

def test_comprehension(n):
    foo = [i for i in range(n)]
    return foo

list_size_steps = 7  # 10 to 10 million
list_size = 10
num_elements = 60_000_000

print(f"*** python: {sys.version.split(' ')[0]} ***")
for _ in range(list_size_steps):
    test_num = int(num_elements / list_size)
    print(f"{list_size=}, {test_num=}")

    time_loops = timeit.timeit("test_loop(list_size)", globals=globals(), number=test_num)
    time_comprehension = timeit.timeit("test_comprehension(list_size)", globals=globals(), number=test_num)
    pct = round(time_loops / time_comprehension, 4)
    print("\tLoops vs Comp: {:3.0%} :: {:1.4f} vs {:1.4f}".format(pct, time_loops, time_comprehension))

    list_size *= 10
    print()
```

Result:

**Python 3.12.1:**

```
*** python: 3.12.1 ***
list_size=10, test_num=6000000
    Loops vs Comp: 121% :: 1.3279 vs 1.0990

list_size=100, test_num=600000
    Loops vs Comp: 143% :: 0.8200 vs 0.5727

list_size=1000, test_num=60000
    Loops vs Comp: 128% :: 1.0748 vs 0.8421

list_size=10000, test_num=6000
    Loops vs Comp: 124% :: 1.1820 vs 0.9527

list_size=100000, test_num=600
    Loops vs Comp: 120% :: 1.5919 vs 1.3287

list_size=1000000, test_num=60
    Loops vs Comp: 116% :: 1.7638 vs 1.5161

list_size=10000000, test_num=6
    Loops vs Comp: 114% :: 1.9591 vs 1.7146
```

**Python 3.11.7:**

```
*** python: 3.11.7 ***
list_size=10, test_num=6000000
    Loops vs Comp: 81% :: 1.3323 vs 1.6385 <--- THIS!

list_size=100, test_num=600000
    Loops vs Comp: 129% :: 0.7914 vs 0.6140

list_size=1000, test_num=60000
    Loops vs Comp: 116% :: 0.8822 vs 0.7592

list_size=10000, test_num=6000
    Loops vs Comp: 113% :: 0.9733 vs 0.8584

list_size=100000, test_num=600
    Loops vs Comp: 112% :: 1.3436 vs 1.2003

list_size=1000000, test_num=60
    Loops vs Comp: 111% :: 1.5391 vs 1.3831

list_size=10000000, test_num=6
    Loops vs Comp: 109% :: 1.7964 vs 1.6524
```

### Update: Decided to add numbers for Python 3.10 and 3.9 too.

As you can see, the list comprehension performance issue only affected Python 3.11. Older and newer versions are not affected, at least among the Python versions I've tested (3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12).

**Python 3.10.13:**

```
*** python: 3.10.13 ***
list_size=10, test_num=6000000
    Loops vs Comp: 125% :: 2.3019 vs 1.8439

list_size=100, test_num=600000
    Loops vs Comp: 217% :: 1.6378 vs 0.7552

list_size=1000, test_num=60000
    Loops vs Comp: 201% :: 1.8167 vs 0.9029

list_size=10000, test_num=6000
    Loops vs Comp: 190% :: 1.7905 vs 0.9442

list_size=100000, test_num=600
    Loops vs Comp: 158% :: 2.2074 vs 1.3967

list_size=1000000, test_num=60
    Loops vs Comp: 151% :: 2.4325 vs 1.6135

list_size=10000000, test_num=6
    Loops vs Comp: 142% :: 2.5604 vs 1.8094
```

**Python 3.9.18:**

```
*** python: 3.9.18 ***
list_size=10, test_num=6000000
    Loops vs Comp: 129% :: 2.1633 vs 1.6834

list_size=100, test_num=600000
    Loops vs Comp: 190% :: 1.4944 vs 0.7847

list_size=1000, test_num=60000
    Loops vs Comp: 194% :: 1.8775 vs 0.9685

list_size=10000, test_num=6000
    Loops vs Comp: 158% :: 2.3659 vs 1.4978

list_size=100000, test_num=600
    Loops vs Comp: 151% :: 2.4121 vs 1.5974

list_size=1000000, test_num=60
    Loops vs Comp: 147% :: 2.5078 vs 1.7022

list_size=10000000, test_num=6
    Loops vs Comp: 139% :: 2.7699 vs 1.9927
```

Comment: "For short loops with low amounts of .append(), list comprehension's overhead seems to be slower, as seen in my original question." it isn't slower. You should compare just the list comprehension against the loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga **It's not even debatable.** The work done in both functions in my original question are *identical.* The only difference is that one uses list comprehension and the other uses a for-loop. And me and my friend consistently got 8-20% slower performance in the list comprehension version. I even inverted the order of the tests to check for "CPU warmup/throttling", and loop ALWAYS WON by a SIGNIFICANT margin. :) There is a REAL difference between the setup bytecode of a list comprehension vs a simple loop. But as the amount of `.append()` grows, comprehension wins.

Comment: It *is debatable* since *empirically* that is what I'm observing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nah, if I delete the `for k in remove_keys: del new_settings[k]` lines from both tests in my original code, and do 30 million iterations, list comprehension is still 4.3% slower than for-append.

Comment: Don't re-create the dictionary for every test, re-use the same dictionary (just make it global)

Comment: In any case, I don't disagree with your overall conclusion

Comment: `py -m timeit -s "x=[]" "for i in range(100_000): x.append(i)"` -> 8.81 msec per loop.  `py -m timeit -s "x=[i for i in range(100_000)]"` -> 19.3 nsec per loop.  Sure seems like comp is faster.

Comment: @MarkTolonen that's a bad comparison, move the loop into a function, because what you are seeing here is basically the difference between hash-based (global) lookups, and array-based (local) lookups

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes for situations with lots of `.append()`, like your 100 000 items, list comprehension is way faster. That's not under debate. :) That part was established already.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers it's not way faster. It's marginally faster.

Comment: with `range(10)` it was still 901ns (append) vs. 20.1ns (comp).

Comment: @MarkTolonen you *have to put them both inside local scopes to make the comparison here fair*. For `range(100_00)`, inside a function, I'm getting only a 2x speed up, not orders of magnitude differences

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, since I am no longer deleting keys, I can make the test-dicts global. If I do that, **List Comprehension is 9% slower than for-append when the list is small.** I'll edit my answer to include that new test.

Comment: actually I screwed up anyway.  I left the -s on the comp in so only ran once :)  Done correclty (and still without local scope comparison) it was closer.

Comment: With local functions, 820ns (loop) vs. 712ns (comp) for range(10), 8.4ms (loop) vs. 6.43ms (comp) for range(100_000).  Much closer, but even small range comps were marginally faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga **We were both right. I found the reason now: Python 3.12 has optimized List Comprehensions. In Python 3.11 (and older, presumably), they were slower than `for-append()`.** If I switch to Python 3.12, list comprehension is always faster. I've edited my answer. Thanks for helping debug this and trying various things until the reason was found!

Comment: I didn't go thru your code. But I've personally checked before. My observation was also Pythonic one liners are slower than the tradition python coding.

Comment: @SuramuthuR not in general, no, the equivalent list comprehension is usually marginally faster than an equivalent loop. As the size of the list increases, and the work done in the mapping/filtering part increases, the differences become trivial